# Javascript NodeJS - too many request at once?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I have problem with request, because about 1-3 requests run away and I don't know why. I put two variables: counter and check, they should be equal but generally they don't.

If I check this on small data, e.g. 1 service, it works, but for all the data has not working.

```
var request = require('request');

var UserAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101     Firefox/36.0'

var check = ""
var counter = ""

services = [
{
    name: "otodom",
    url: 'http://otodom.pl/',
    css_selector: '.search__counter',
    sell: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=House',
            terrain: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Terrain',
            flat: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Flat',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=House',
            terrain: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Terrain',
            flat: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Flat',
        }
    },
    rent: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=rent&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=House',
            terrain: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=rent&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Terrain',
            flat: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=rent&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Flat',
            room: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=rent&objSearchQuery.OnlyFromRegularUser=y&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Room',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=House',
            terrain: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Terrain',
            flat: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Flat',
            room: 'http://otodom.pl/index.php?mod=listing&source=context&objSearchQuery.OfferType=sell&objSearchQuery.ObjectName=Room',
        }
    }
},
{
    name: "olx",
    url: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/',
    css_selector: '.color-2',
    sell: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/domy/sprzedaz/',
            terrain: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/dzialki/sprzedaz/',
            flat: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/sprzedaz/',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/sprzedaz/',
            terrain: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/dzialki/sprzedaz/',
            flat: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/sprzedaz/',
        }
    },
    rent: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/domy/wynajem/',
            terrain: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/dzialki/wynajem/',
            room: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/stancje-pokoje/',
            flat: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/',
            terrain: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/dzialki/wynajem/',
            room: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/stancje-pokoje/',
            flat: 'http://olx.pl/nieruchomosci/mieszkania/wynajem/',
        }
    }
},
{
    name: "gratka.pl",
    url: 'http://dom.gartka.pl/',
    css_selector: '.ilosc',
    sell: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/domy-sprzedam/lista/,,on,zi.html',
            terrain: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/dzialki-grunty-sprzedam/lista/,,on,zi.html',
            flat: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/mieszkania-sprzedam/lista/,,on,zi.html',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/domy-sprzedam/lista/',
            terrain: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/dzialki-grunty-sprzedam/lista/',
            flat: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/mieszkania-sprzedam/lista/',
        }
    },
    rent: {
        individual: {
            house: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/domy-do-wynajecia/lista/,,on,zi.html',
            terrain: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/dzialki-grunty-do-wydzierzawienia/lista/,,on,zi.html',
            room: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/pokoje-do-wynajecia/lista/,,on,zi.html',
            flat: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/mieszkania-do-wynajecia/lista/,,on,zi.html',
        },
        totalUser: {
            house: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/domy-do-wynajecia/lista/',
            terrain: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/dzialki-grunty-do-wydzierzawienia/lista/',
            room: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/pokoje-do-wynajecia/lista/',
            flat: 'http://dom.gratka.pl/mieszkania-do-wynajecia/lista/',
        }
    }
}
```

]

And this is a short script

```
function do_get (page, category, typ, user, service) {
   counter += '1'
   console.log(counter.length)
   request({url: page, headers: {'User-Agent': UserAgent}}, function(buffer,   res, body) {
     check += '1'
     console.log(check.length)
});
```

}

```
function do_that (service) {
    for(var user in service.sell) {
        var users = service.sell[user];
        for (var category in users) {
            do_get(users[category], category, "sell", user, service);
       }
    }
    for(var user in service.rent) {
         var users = service.rent[user];
         for (var category in users) {
            do_get(users[category], category, "rent", user, service);
         }
    }
}

for(var i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
    do_that(services[i]);
}
```

Comment: Anytime one or more requests is running, `counter` and `check` won't be the same.  Other than that, I don't see what the question is.

Comment: I do not know why I did not get a response from all the url

Comment: Do you realize that you're firing ALL your requests at once so they will all hit the server in rapid succession and then you are awaiting all the results.  It is likely you are exceeding a node.js socket limit.

Comment: Yes, I know that all these requests launched at once, but I don't know how to do this in that way that launching this step by step. I tried write function with callback, but still I can't achieving my goal.